# Why do Pokemon sometimes have dark stripes in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Occasionally I'll face a Charizard or Venusaur in GBL that has dark striping like this:

[image]

How do they get those markings, or what is the significance of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are clone Pokémon, which were [available in 4-star raids during Pokémon Day 2020](https://pokemongolive.com/post/pokemonday2020/?hl=en). They are just cosmetic variants of Venusaur, Charizard, Blastoise, and Pikachu.

[image: Clone Blastoise, Charizard, and Venusaur]

The evolved clone starters came with their respective Community Day charge move, so you can expect them to have it even at low MMR.

Comment: I assume they are a reference to the first Pokemon movie?

Comment: @Stef Definitely yes.

Comment: Technically, it was to promote the 2019 Remake of the first movie ;)